# Remove columns where all items in column are identical (excluding header) and match a specified string

Tags: python, pandas

My question is an extension of [Delete Column in Pandas based on Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164910/delete-column-in-pandas-based-on-condition), but I have headers and the information isn't binary. Instead of removing a column containing all zeros, I'd like to be able to pass a variable "search_var" (containing a string) to filter out columns containing only that string.

I initially thought I should read in the df and iterate across each column, read each column in as a list, and print columns where len(col_list) > 2 and search_var not in col_list. The solution provided to the previous post involving a boolean dataframe (df != search_var) intrigued me there might be a simpler way, but how could I go around the issue that the header will not match and therefore cannot purely filter on True/False?

What I have (non-working):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('input.tsv', dtype=str)
with open('output.tsv', 'aw') as ofh:
    df['col_list'] = list(df.values)
    if len(col_list) < 3 and search_var not in col_list:
        df.to_csv(ofh, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', header=False)
```

## Example input, search_var = 'red'

```
Name  Header1 Header2 Header3
name1 red     red     red
name2 red     orange  red
name3 red     yellow  red
name4 red     green   red
name5 red     blue    blue
```

## Expected Output

```
Name  Header2 Header3
name1 red     red
name2 orange  red
name3 yellow  red
name4 green   red
name5 blue    blue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the number of `non-red` item in the column, if it is not zero then select it using `loc`:

```
df.loc[:, (df != 'red').sum() != 0]

#    Name   Header2   Header3
# 0 name1       red       red
# 1 name2    orange       red
# 2 name3    yellow       red
# 3 name4     green       red
# 4 name5      blue      blue
```