# Removing one-hot encoded columns if all 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df`, which has a bunch of observations that have a bunch of categories that they can belong to and whether they won or not. I subsetted some of the rows so there are actually more categories. I want to create a new dataframe where I remove any category columns (any column with prefix `cat_`) that don't correspond to any of the observations (i.e. the whole category column is 0).

```
id cat_food    cat_fitness   cat_retail    cat_grocery  win
1  1           0             1             0            1
2  1           0             0             0            0
3  0           1             0             0            1
4  1           0             0             0            1
4  1           0             0             0            0
5  1           0             0             0            1
6  0           1             1             0            1
6  0           1             1             0            0
```

my expected dataframe would have the column `cat_grocery` removed because none of the observations belong to that category

```
id cat_food    cat_fitness   cat_retail      win
1  1           0             1               1
2  1           0             0               0
3  0           1             0               1
4  1           0             0               1
4  1           0             0               0
5  1           0             0               1
6  0           1             1               1
6  0           1             1               0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a column that contains only zeros in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164910/how-do-i-delete-a-column-that-contains-only-zeros-in-pandas)

Comment: `df.loc[:, df.max()>0]` or `df.loc[:, df.any()]`?

Comment: I only want to delete columns with a `cat_` prefix that have all zeros, not any column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:
*I remove any category columns (any column with prefix cat_) that don't correspond to any of the observations (i.e. the whole category column is 0)* , you can chain the conditions to check if sum is 0 and if column has a prefix `cat_` using `str.startswith` , and then use it with loc:

```
df.loc[:,~(df.sum().eq(0) & df.columns.str.startswith("cat_"))]

   id  cat_food  cat_fitness  cat_retail  win
0   1         1            0           1    1
1   2         1            0           0    0
2   3         0            1           0    1
3   4         1            0           0    1
4   4         1            0           0    0
5   5         1            0           0    1
6   6         0            1           1    1
7   6         0            1           1    0
```